# Access an element inside NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have two classes:

`MusicQuestion` which has this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *answers; // array of MPMediaItem
```

`MusicQuiz` which has this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSMutableArray *questions; // array of MusicQuestion
```

I want to access, from `MusicQuiz`, `answers[0]` inside `question[0]`. I tried this:

```
[self.question[0] answers] // It only access the entire array of the first question
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already accessed the answers array, now simply access the item within the array:

```
MPMediaItem *item = [self.question[0] answers][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *answers = [self.questions[0] answers];  //This is the answers array of the first question
MPMediaItem *item = answers[0]; //This is that MPMediaItem you want.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MPMediaItem *item = [[self.question[0] answers] objectAtIndex:0];
```